# Как получить уровень громкости (dB) системный Windows | Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, аудио, windows-10

Как можно получить текущий уровень в dB или процентах (например когда слушаю музыку) в python ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите пожалуйста как вы слушаете музыку в Python.

Comment: В децибелах очевидно никак - у одного слабенький спикер у другого может быть крутой профессиональный звук с мощными колонками.

Comment: @MaxU в децибелах также измеряется ослабление звука системным микшером, только со знаком минус (0dB =100%)

Comment: Мне надо всего получить уровень вот этой https://i.ibb.co/1MLtKN3/image.png